# Convert To HTML Azure Powershell "Get-VM"

Tags: html, css, powershell, azure

I have an problem of overriding parameters in my Azure Powershell Script.

Into my $VMs I have a few $VM(Virtual Machines) and when I try to convert them to HTML file with table format(Columns of: Name, IP address, PowerState) I only get the final $VM because my Foreach and IF loops override all other VMs.

I would also love to some tips and feedback about better and correct code writing.

**This is my Full Code:**

```
$style = "<style>"
$style += "BODY{background-color: #6D7B8D;}"
$style += "TABLE{border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0px auto}"
$style += "TH{border-width: 1px; padding: 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color:#3300CC}"
$style += "TD{border-width: 1px; padding: 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color:#659EC7}"
$style += "</style>"
$title = "<H2 align=center>IIS Pool Status</H2>"
$destination = "C:\Users\<User>\Desktop\Test.htm"

$VMs = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "<CloudService>"

foreach ($VM in $VMs)
{
    #Check if the current VM has an Endpoints with Port 80(HTTP) or Port 443(HTTPS)
    $HTTPEndpoint = Get-AzureEndpoint -VM $VM | Where { $_.Port -in 80, 443}
    if ($HTTPEndpoint)
    {
        '1', '2' | 
        Select @{label='VM Name';expression={$VM.Name}}, @{label='IP Address';expression={$VM.IPAddress}}, @{label='Power State';expression={$VM.PowerState}} | 
        ConvertTo-HTML -head $style -body $title | 
        Out-File $destination 
    }
}
Invoke-Expression $destination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out-File overwrites the file, unless you use -Append so the final execution of the loop will determine the content.

HtH,
Gareth